# How to fix 2D animation while player walks?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make my character idle, run, jump and fall. I did it, but i have bug with runing animation. While he goes left or right, he doesn't play animation "run", which called by integer "noob" with parameter "2",he plays animation "fall", which "noob" is parameter "4"

I'm using Unity 4.5.x and C# code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class movement : MonoBehaviour {

Rigidbody2D rb;
Animator anim;
public int jumpCount = 0;
public Camera main;
float jumpTimer = 0;

void Start () {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.X) && jumpCount < 2 && jumpTimer == 0) {
        jump ();
        jumpCount += 1;
        jumpTimer = 1;
        StartCoroutine("jumpTime");
    }
    if (rb.velocity.y > 0) {
        Flip();
        anim.SetInteger ("noob", 3);
    }
    if (rb.velocity.y < 0) {
        Flip();
        anim.SetInteger ("noob", 4);
    }
    if (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") == 0 && rb.velocity.y == 0) {
        anim.SetInteger ("noob", 1);
    }
    if (rb.velocity.y == 0 && Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") != 0) {
        Flip();
        anim.SetInteger("noob", 2);
    }
    if (rb.velocity.y == 0) {
        jumpCount = 0;
    }
}

void FixedUpdate(){
    rb.velocity = new Vector2 (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") * 12f, rb.velocity.y);
}

void jump(){
    rb.AddForce (transform.up * 14F, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}
void Flip() {
    if (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") > 0) {
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, 0);
    }
    if (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") < 0) {
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler (0, 180, 0);
    }
}
IEnumerator jumpTime() {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.4f);
    jumpTimer = 0;
}
}
```

I tried to do something with jumCount, jumpTimer and velocity.y, but nothing helped

Comment: Might be that the y velocity is in fact different from zero while he walks due to float imprecision. Try printing the velocity. If this is the case, instead of checking for equal zero, check for smaller than some threshold. Other than that, give your variables proper names, giving them "funny" names like "noob" will result in you not understanding your own code after a while.

Comment: well, i changed my "noob" to "animTrigger"
i think in future i will understand my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggested making a grounded and jumping bool, you can use this bool to determine whether your character is airbourne. Also using else if conditional statements may help here to avoid setting your value more than once. Then you can do something like this:

```
if (grounded && jumping) {
    Flip();
    anim.SetInteger ("noob", 3);
    jumping = false;
}
else if (!grounded) {
    Flip();
    anim.SetInteger ("noob", 4);
}
else if (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") == 0 && grounded) {
    anim.SetInteger ("noob", 1);
}
else if (grounded && Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") != 0) {
    Flip();
    anim.SetInteger("noob", 2);
}
```

Comment: thanks, Branden, but now i have problem with jump animation - it doesnt even show it!

Comment: You need to be setting your booleans somewhere in your code. Find the place where you are initialising your jump (probably addforce) and set your jump variable to true. Also when you jump make sure that you set grounded to false, and make grounded true when your player lands again.